# why php mysql insert data is only working with first query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty new to php web development and i am stuck on this bit of code for a while. Currently the data is only being entered into the first table. A little nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
$first = isset($_GET['first']) ? $_GET['first']: '';
$last  = isset($_GET['last']) ? $_GET['last'] : '';
$email = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email']: '';
$pass  = isset($_GET['pass']) ? $_GET['pass']: '';
$groupname = isset($_GET['groupname']) ? $_GET['groupname'] : '';
$grouppass  = isset($_GET['grouppassword']) ? $_GET['grouppassword']: '';
define("DB_SERVER", "x");
define("DB_USER", "x");
define("DB_PASS", "x");
define("DB_NAME", "x");
define("TBL_USERS", "Members");
define("TBL_GROUP", "group");

function addNewUser($firstname, $lastname, $email, $password){
    global $connection; 
    $password1 = md5($password);
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($firstname);
    $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);
    $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email',   '$password1','')";
    return mysql_query($q, $connection);
}

$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
addNewUser($first,$last,$email,$pass);
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".TBL_GROUP." VALUES ('$groupname', '$grouppass')");
```

Comment: nice [sql injection holes](http://bobby-tables). I'm surprised even your "first" query is working properly. Even more surprising is that you're using escaping on two values, but neglect the rest of them...

Comment: If you're new to php, please don't learn a depreciated extension... "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also the MySQL API Overview for further help while choosing a MySQL API." http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: Thanks for the advise! Switching to MySQLi

Answer (score 0):

Try to Make a common connection and after getting the connection to be success. try to insert much more query as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Check your table structure for 'TBL_GROUP'. You can try to insert a row via your sql in that table using phpmyadmin's 'SQL' interface / or you can use 'INSERT' interface. You will know what is wrong (possibly something in your TBL structure is creating problem).